# Manually creating a GPG Public Key

Tags: hash, public-key, signature, certificates, pgp

I want to manually create a GPG public key that can be imported into GPG, i.e. I want to create a file with a Public-Key Packet, a User ID Packet and a Signature Packet (for an example see [here](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----%0A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%0A7q5zlW2IBgrphrjOhcaW%0A=nqVa%0A-----END+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----)). I already managed to correctly create a Public-Key Packet with a User ID Packet and a Signature Packet, except for the hash/signature of the Signature Packet.

I tried to hash data as described in [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.4), however the description there is rather imprecise. For example it does not state what exactly constitutes a public key body (is it only *n* or also the public exponent *e*?) or if "tags" are to be hashed as well. With tags I mean fixed data preceding certain elements of a packet (e.g. for the public exponent e the tag is 00 11; see [here](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----%0A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%0A7q5zlW2IBgrphrjOhcaW%0A=nqVa%0A-----END+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----)).

Unfortunately the [GPG source code](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg) and its resulting binary are also not very helpful for understanding what data exactly is hashed. I am currently tracing the export function (i.e. gpg --export) but I can't find the function that is used to hash the data for the Signature Packet (interestingly enough, neither the hash_public_key() function in g10/keyid.c nor the make_keysig_packet() function in g10/sign.c seem to be used for that).

Does anyone know what exactly is hashed and can exemplify it?

Comment: i found the solution, i will post it shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example given in the question (see [here](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----%0A%0AmQENBF70osYBCACoFG2zdRJyMx6SVMVD9kTSIl1Nmwy4XWBgi/A5CB4xKeL1TIPg%0Acbci4/h4m8SiwapwcjrrxR7s0WWbWFAg9NA223nIJGq9Qz8IKGw1shYwaxRMlHRa%0A+oVaBY0GO5Qp8Zhx9ARIm4TvuZRl65wKl7bSRhNkQlcT6ghIYl8k6vPV9Stytpbg%0Ar6xLaEGv/GTNVaF1BTPtC3iibNQz1dtqcnh4nK5FdAjSQHIwTfJi6ilu2ehdEs+g%0AeuZgRCkGdU/QccifNYpFUkUgBHp5zFSOuhAbrvCeJGhWmBgQK/WVwVpQV1pHb+Vh%0ARPcvhv6MVKFNqBNo5uK0V6ov+sUG/BNHmCPHABEBAAG0HEdQRyBUZXN0IEtleSA8%0AdGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbT6JAU4EEwEKADgWIQRDP7xVq20JFyETGDp5Glq+PmJElQUC%0AXvSixgIbLwULCQgHAgYVCgkICwIEFgIDAQIeAQIXgAAKCRB5Glq+PmJElS+bB/4o%0AoiPGrzfx+sXCrpy9f7kEvRo+nWQvGju7VbuJefXT4qeOVltdWHbz/HgyLrOBNegL%0ADp6OY+4tvkbw2ihpnVcxHzy0Y0lJbGNlR3s2lJfq4fd1MjIVbC8yhja54ncw3T/M%0AMCKYD237MHWuDK6Gj/Cw8ggJpaWXL9uo1+JZ3cyJEMvuFBP2brBGEgBST7aH9Oha%0AnpkCPdsPS8PUXbgjTO0ZXnOrUNL8NwVEj3UM6M2k2X9tRSxyaw8r6u5ENARbRmc7%0A1D6f371Po8tAlOrH1S3rkewT/TxCqrkrOxg0T2kfG4DsVBH+DZRo45qfsITaLSmD%0A7q5zlW2IBgrphrjOhcaW%0A=nqVa%0A-----END+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----)) the following (hex-encoded) bytes would be hashed:

**From the Public-Key Packet**

```
Ciphertype Byte: 99 

Key Length: 01 0d 

Version: 04 

CreatedAt: 5e f4 a2 c6 

Algorithm: 01 

n (with tag): 08 00 a8 14 6d b3 75 12 72 33 1e 92 54 c5 43 f6 44 d2 22 5d 4d 9b 0c b8 5d 60 60 8b f0 39 08 1e 31 29 e2 f5 4c 83 e0 71 b7 22 e3 f8 78 9b c4 a2 c1 aa 70 72 3a eb c5 1e ec d1 65 9b 58 50 20 f4 d0 36 db 79 c8 24 6a bd 43 3f 08 28 6c 35 b2 16 30 6b 14 4c 94 74 5a fa 85 5a 05 8d 06 3b 94 29 f1 98 71 f4 04 48 9b 84 ef b9 94 65 eb 9c 0a 97 b6 d2 46 13 64 42 57 13 ea 08 48 62 5f 24 ea f3 d5 f5 2b 72 b6 96 e0 af ac 4b 68 41 af fc 64 cd 55 a1 75 05 33 ed 0b 78 a2 6c d4 33 d5 db 6a 72 78 78 9c ae 45 74 08 d2 40 72 30 4d f2 62 ea 29 6e d9 e8 5d 12 cf a0 7a e6 60 44 29 06 75 4f d0 71 c8 9f 35 8a 45 52 45 20 04 7a 79 cc 54 8e ba 10 1b ae f0 9e 24 68 56 98 18 10 2b f5 95 c1 5a 50 57 5a 47 6f e5 61 44 f7 2f 86 fe 8c 54 a1 4d a8 13 68 e6 e2 b4 57 aa 2f fa c5 06 fc 13 47 98 23 c7 

e (with tag): 00 11 01 00 01
```

**From the User ID Packet**

```
Ciphertype Byte: b4 

Length: 00 00 00 1c 

UserID: 47 50 47 20 54 65 73 74 20 4b 65 79 20 3c 74 65 73 74 40 74 65 73 74 2e 63 6f 6d 3e
```

**From the Signature Packet**

```
Version: 04 

Signature Type: 13 

Public Key Algorithm: 01
 
Hash Algorithm: 0a 

Hashed Data Count: 00 38 

Undefined Subpacket Length: 16 

Undefined Subpacket Type: 21 

Undefined Subpacket Data: 04 43 3f bc 55 ab 6d 09 17 21 13 18 3a 79 1a 5a be 3e 62 44 95 

Creation Time Subpacket Length: 05 

Creation Time Subpacket Type: 02 

Creation Time Subpacket Data: 5e f4 a2 c6 

Key Flags Subpacket Length: 02 

Key Flags Subpacket Type: 1b 

Key Flags Subpacket Data: 2f 

Preferred Symmetric Algorithms Subpacket Length: 05 

Preferred Symmetric Algorithms Subpacket Type: 0b 

Preferred Symmetric Algorithms Subpacket Data: 09 08 07 02 

Preferred Hash Algorithms Subpacket Length: 06 

Preferred Hash Algorithms Subpacket Type: 15 

Preferred Hash Algorithms Subpacket Data: 0a 09 08 0b 02 

Preferred Compression Algorithms Subpacket Length: 04 

Preferred Compression Algorithms Subpacket Type: 16 

Preferred Compression Algorithms Subpacket Data: 02 03 01 

Features Subpacket Length: 02 

Features Subpacket Type: 1e 

Features Subpacket Data: 01 

Key Server Preferences Subpacket Length: 02 

Key Server Preferences Subpacket Type: 17 

Key Server Preferences Subpacket Data: 80
```

**Other Data**

```
Trailer: 04 ff 

Big-Endian Count of Hashed Signature Packet Data: 00 00 00 3e
```

**Full Byte Array**
(i.e. a concatenation of the bytes in 'From the Public-Key Packet', 'From the User ID Packet', 'From the Signature Packet', and 'Other Data'):

```
99 01 0d 04 5e f4 a2 c6 01 08 00 a8 14 6d b3 75 12 72 33 1e 92 54 c5 43 f6 44 d2 22 5d 4d 9b 0c b8 5d 60 60 8b f0 39 08 1e 31 29 e2 f5 4c 83 e0 71 b7 22 e3 f8 78 9b c4 a2 c1 aa 70 72 3a eb c5 1e ec d1 65 9b 58 50 20 f4 d0 36 db 79 c8 24 6a bd 43 3f 08 28 6c 35 b2 16 30 6b 14 4c 94 74 5a fa 85 5a 05 8d 06 3b 94 29 f1 98 71 f4 04 48 9b 84 ef b9 94 65 eb 9c 0a 97 b6 d2 46 13 64 42 57 13 ea 08 48 62 5f 24 ea f3 d5 f5 2b 72 b6 96 e0 af ac 4b 68 41 af fc 64 cd 55 a1 75 05 33 ed 0b 78 a2 6c d4 33 d5 db 6a 72 78 78 9c ae 45 74 08 d2 40 72 30 4d f2 62 ea 29 6e d9 e8 5d 12 cf a0 7a e6 60 44 29 06 75 4f d0 71 c8 9f 35 8a 45 52 45 20 04 7a 79 cc 54 8e ba 10 1b ae f0 9e 24 68 56 98 18 10 2b f5 95 c1 5a 50 57 5a 47 6f e5 61 44 f7 2f 86 fe 8c 54 a1 4d a8 13 68 e6 e2 b4 57 aa 2f fa c5 06 fc 13 47 98 23 c7 00 11 01 00 01 b4 00 00 00 1c 47 50 47 20 54 65 73 74 20 4b 65 79 20 3c 74 65 73 74 40 74 65 73 74 2e 63 6f 6d 3e 04 13 01 0a 00 38 16 21 04 43 3f bc 55 ab 6d 09 17 21 13 18 3a 79 1a 5a be 3e 62 44 95 05 02 5e f4 a2 c6 02 1b 2f 05 0b 09 08 07 02 06 15 0a 09 08 0b 02 04 16 02 03 01 02 1e 01 02 17 80 04 ff 00 00 00 3e
```

**Resulting Hash**

```
2f 9b ad fd 89 90 e9 34 f3 15 c6 9c c5 8e 45 12 47 29 fe ab e6 18 a2 e2 71 fb bf e1 9e 20 10 8a 86 ea d9 dd 5b 87 58 87 45 85 98 2a 68 14 e9 e2 ef 9e b6 07 12 1d 9b 7c 15 8f 58 79 c2 92 c5 e9
```

The two first bytes of the generated hash are shown in the signedHashValuePrefix of [the used example](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----%0A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%0A7q5zlW2IBgrphrjOhcaW%0A=nqVa%0A-----END+PGP+PUBLIC+KEY+BLOCK-----) (which was generated with the GPG CLI).