# Signing a GPG Public Key

Tags: public-key, signature, padding, pgp

I am trying to manually create a GPG Public Key (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81783/manually-creating-a-gpg-public-key)). I am able to generate a GPG Public Key with a correct hash, but fail to RSA-sign that hash in a way that is accepted by the GPG CLI. For the GPG Public Key I have created see [here](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN%20PGP%20PUBLIC%20KEY%20BLOCK-----%0A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%0ALx95FljA+3RK3QRzV/jX%0A=8T3I%0A%0A-----END%20PGP%20PUBLIC%20KEY%20BLOCK-----).

To sign the hash I am using a private key on a PKCS#11 HSM. The HSM supports various signing mechanisms. I have tried signing with RSA-PKCS-PSS (with hash algorithm SHA512 and mask generation function MGF1-SHA512), SHA512-RSA-PKCS, and SHA512-RSA-PKCS-PSS, but neither produces a signature that the *import* command of the GPG CLI accepts. I suppose the GPG CLI expects a different padding.

Unfortunately, [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) does not explicitely cover GPG Public Key signature padding, but only specifies that EME-PKCS1-v1_5 and EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 functions are used for PKCS#1 encoding. A quick search through the GPG source code shows that both PKCS#1 v1.5 and PSS are used at some points.

Does anybody know what padding exactly is supported in the *import* command of the GPG CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're barking up the wrong tree.**

To answer the stated question, OpenPGP doesn't support or use RSA-PSS, at least not yet. For RSA signature, EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 from PKCS1, referenced as rfc3447 (which republished PKCS1v2.1) and actually copied for your convenience into rfc4880 13.1.3 (though without the precomputed DigestInfo encodings), *is* the hash *and* padding together. Other PGP signature algorithms don't use padding (or only trivially). And it's not just the CLI; PGP protocols and formats are the same for all modes of GPG.

But your *padding* is fine; it's the hash that's wrong. In your posted message-and-decode, the signature given is a valid v1_5 signature for the SHA512 hash
`89 6e e3 83 f0 24 e7 ba 4e 12 87 36 bd dd 55 fb 1d 8e 20 b0 f2 72 c6 3c e3 53 29 23 47 41 28 c9 b7 f4 51 ea 39 cd 1c ae ee 29 c2 e4 d4 13 fb 05 dd 89 bd 6b f7 20 76 63 95 f5 f8 b7 79 b2 d1 1b`
-- or to be exact, since the v1_5 signature scheme includes hashing, it is the signature for data with that SHA512 hash. However, as shown in your previous Q&A, the correct hash for this publickey is `2f 9b ad fd 89 90 e9 34 f3 15 c6 9c c5 8e 45 12 47 29 fe ab e6 18 a2 e2 71 fb bf e1 9e 20 10 8a 86 ea d9 dd 5b 87 58 87 45 85 98 2a 68 14 e9 e2 ef 9e b6 07 12 1d 9b 7c 15 8f 58 79 c2 92 c5 e9`. The former value is in fact the SHA512 hash of the latter, aka the hash of the hash. Probably you have given the hash value as data to a signing mechanism that both hashes and signs its input -- as v1_5 signature implementations usually do, so they can ensure the same hash is applied to the data as is encoded in the DigestInfo. In particular a mechanism named 'SHA512-RSA-PKCS' almost certainly applies the hash (SHA512) AND pads and modexps the result.

To fix your actual problem, you should give the data not the hash as input to the signing mechanism, and not change anything relating to padding in any way.

Comment: to add some context for others: RSA-PKCS-PSS (with hash algorithm SHA512 and mask generation function MGF1-SHA512) takes a SHA512 hash, while SHA512-RSA-PKCS generates the SHA512 hash itself. 

i found documentation on the behavior of different PKCS#11 signing mechanisms: https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__12__MECHANISMS.html